# How to extract one or more words from a string and search for them in two different columns form another file in R

Tags: r, string, match

I need to find which rows of df1 are present in df2 by extracting for the words after "gene_id" in df1$Id and searching for them in 2 different columns of df2 (df2$Gene.id, df2$Gene.name).

This is how my data looks:

```
df1 <- data_frame(
  Chr = c("NC_035077.1", "NC_035078.1", "NC_035083.1", "NC_035083.1", "NC_035084.1", "NC_035084.1", "NC_035088.1"),
  Pos = c("61344375", "78462810", "24378412", "24387264","66360216", "66360385","40131947"),
  Var=c("tco","born", "tco","tco", "born","tco","tco"),
  Id=c("gene_id calm2", "gene_id LOC110500174", "gene_id ahcy", "gene_id ahcy", "gene_id cebpd", "gene_id cebpd", "gene_id LOC110537636, gene_id hsc70a")
  )

df1
Chr         Pos      Var   Id                                  
  <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <chr>                               
1 NC_035077.1 61344375 tco   gene_id calm2                       
2 NC_035078.1 78462810 born  gene_id LOC110500174                
3 NC_035083.1 24378412 tco   gene_id ahcy                        
4 NC_035083.1 24387264 tco   gene_id ahcy                        
5 NC_035084.1 66360216 born  gene_id cebpd                       
6 NC_035084.1 66360385 tco   gene_id cebpd                       
7 NC_035088.1 40131947 tco   gene_id LOC110537636, gene_id hsc70a


df2 <- data_frame(
  Gene.id = c("LOC110488122", "NA", "LOC110490243", "LOC110537256", "LOC100136165", "LOC100379112", "LOC100379114", "LOC110527949", "LOC110537636"),
  Gene.name = c("agr2", "agrn", "ahcy", "akap1","cebpb", "cebpb","cebpd", "ddost","slc6a13")
  )
 
df2
 Gene.id      Gene.name
  <chr>        <chr>    
1 LOC110488122 agr2     
2 NA           agrn     
3 LOC110490243 ahcy     
4 LOC110537256 akap1    
5 LOC100136165 cebpb    
6 LOC100379112 cebpb    
7 LOC100379114 cebpd    
8 LOC110527949 ddost    
9 LOC110537636 slc6a13
```

As you can see some df1$Id have two gene_ids, I need to check for both of them in df2, and whichever of them matches with either df2$Gene.id or df2$Gene.name, I need to include that row in the output file.
Also there are some NAs in df2.

My output should look like this:

```
Chr         Pos      Var   Id                                    Gene.id       Gene.name                                
NC_035083.1 24378412 tco   gene_id ahcy                          LOC110490243  ahcy
NC_035083.1 24387264 tco   gene_id ahcy                          LOC110490243  ahcy
NC_035084.1 66360216 born  gene_id cebpd                         LOC100379114  cebpd 
NC_035084.1 66360385 tco   gene_id cebpd                         LOC100379114  cebpd
NC_035088.1 40131947 tco   gene_id LOC110537636, gene_id hsc70a  LOC110537636  slc6a13
```

Any help on how to achieve this will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick using your example. I'm asuming all your data follows the same format.

You'll need to create a clean "all in" column to join `df1` with `df2`. After doing two joins, clean the useless rows and update the values of the `NA`s using your "all in" column.

### By steps

1. Create new column to separate.
2. Separate the rows with multiple values.
3. Remove the "gene_id " so you can have your clean "all in" column to join.
4. Join by one column then by the other one. Order doesn't matter.
5. Filter rows without any match.
6. Update your `NA`s
7. Remove `new_col` because you don't need it anymore

### Code

```r
library(stringr) # for str_remove()
library(tidyr) # for separate_rows()
library(dplyr) # for everything else

df1 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = Id) %>% 
  separate_rows(new_col, sep = ", ") %>% 
  mutate(new_col = str_remove(new_col, "gene_id ")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("new_col" = "Gene.name")) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("new_col" = "Gene.id")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Gene.name) | !is.na(Gene.id)) %>% 
  mutate(Gene.name = if_else(is.na(Gene.name), new_col, Gene.name),
         Gene.id = if_else(is.na(Gene.id), new_col, Gene.id)) %>% 
  select(-new_col)
```

```
  Chr         Pos      Var   Id                                   Gene.id      Gene.name
  <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <chr>                                <chr>        <chr>    
1 NC_035083.1 24378412 tco   gene_id ahcy                         LOC110490243 ahcy     
2 NC_035083.1 24387264 tco   gene_id ahcy                         LOC110490243 ahcy     
3 NC_035084.1 66360216 born  gene_id cebpd                        LOC100379114 cebpd    
4 NC_035084.1 66360385 tco   gene_id cebpd                        LOC100379114 cebpd    
5 NC_035088.1 40131947 tco   gene_id LOC110537636, gene_id hsc70a LOC110537636 slc6a13
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, as well as, for the explanation. I have already tried it in the whole data set and it works fine. Thanks!!